# Adding WTP nature to an Eclipse project

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

What is the best way to add a WTP nature to my existing project so that I can associate it with my server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand the question:

- Open the project's properties
- Select *Project Facets*
- Check `Dynamic Web Module`

[image]

The *Project Facets* view may contain a message like this:

> This project is not configured to use project facets. Converting this project to faceted form will allow you to easily control the available technologies.
>
> Convert to faceted form...

In this case, just click *Convert to faceted form...* and then you'll be able to check `Dynamic Web Module`.

Comment: Great answer.  Okay.  I have it as a dynamic Web Project, but it is still not allowing me to associate with a server.  Any more thoughts?

Comment: @Joe On above screenshot click on `Runtime` under `Save As...`

Comment: One more issue!  I went to Runtime and everything is grayed out!  The only Facets that I have checked are Java and Dynamic Web Module.